# Optional<Integer> и OptionalInt

Tags: java

В чём отличие `Optional<Integer>` и `OptionalInt`, и в каких случаях какой из этих типов лучше применять?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190768/optionalint-vs-optionalinteger

Comment: Различие между ними такое же, как и между `Integer` и `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отличие в том, что при наличии значения [`Optional<Integer>.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) вернет объект (`Integer`), а [`OptionalInt.getAsInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#getAsInt--) — примитивное значение (`int`).

Соответственно, чтобы избежать лишнего обертывания примитивных значений при работе с `int` применяется `OptionalInt` , а при работе с объектами `Integer` — `Optional<Integer>`.

Рассмотрим на примере интерфейса с двумя методами:

```
interface Test {
    int getInt();
    Integer getInteger();
}
```

При обработке значений имеет смысл использовать соответствующие классы (на примере Stream API):

```
List<Test> list = //получаем список
OptionalInt intFirst = list.stream().mapToInt(Test::getInt).findFirst();
Optional<Integer> integerFirst = list.stream().map(Test::getInteger).findFirst();
```

Использование `IntStream` и `OptionalInt` для поля типа `Integer` потенциально приведет к `NullPointerException`. Использование `Optional<Integer>` и `Stream<Integer>` для `int` приведет к лишнему обертыванию значений.

Необходимость специальных классов обусловлена тем, что в Java примитивные типы не могут использоваться в качестве параметров обобщенных типов. Из за этого классы `Stream<T>` и `Optional<T>` не могут быть использованы для работы с примитивными значениями.

Использовать вместо примитивов классы-обертки непозволительно из-за затрат производительности на упаковку значений в объекты. Поэтому для часто используемых примитивных типов создан набор специальных классов: [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html), [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) и [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html), [`OptionalLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalLong.html), [`OptionalDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html).